# How to remove github actions artifact produced during runtime

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, github-actions-artifacts

During workflow execution, I produce several artifacts but after a successful build I no longer need them and I want to clean that up as I only need them temporarily.

```
- name: Make artifact available to use
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: setup
          path: setup.yml
```

As a part of a different job I need artifacts so I also have

```
- name: Download yaml file
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: setup
```

How can I add a step in the workflow (in my case, the last step) that's gonna remove these artifacts that were produced during runtime?

Comment: Maybe this thread could be useful https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/380

Answer (score 1):

There are [delete artifact actions on the marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=delete+artifact+) that could help you with that.

Example with [this one](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/delete-artifact):

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3

- run: echo hello > world.txt

- name: Make artifact available to use
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: setup
    path: world.txt

# delete-artifact
- uses: geekyeggo/delete-artifact@v1
  with:
    name: setup
```

*I made a workflow run example [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/useful-actions/actions/runs/3014598927) if you want to have a look*.

Comment: Thanks. And this is great, but unfortunately not something I can use within my organization.

Comment: If you're worried about using an open source action inside your organization, you can create your own action or reusable workflow, consuming the Github API: `https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/artifacts/$id` ([example with a bash script doing it](https://gist.github.com/qwe321qwe321qwe321/efae4569576006624c34f23b2dd76a58)

Answer (score 0):

As part of a python API for accessing GitHub.  One of the [examples](https://github.com/AndrewOfC/githubpy/tree/master/examples) provides a tool for waxy repository artifact build-up.   Demo: https://youtu.be/lS37uCKELNM